# How to split paragraph and export to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, paragraph

I am working on a coding project for a former boss who receives hundreds of Emails with exactly the same information every year.

I wrote a code that helped export those emails to excel. However, this year the email body changed. Now it includes a bunch of information in paragraph form.

Here is what the email looks like:

> Name:
>   Do you currently reside in the United States?
>   Address:
>   City:
>   State:
>   Zip Code:
>   Phone:
>   Email:
>   Citizenship:
>   Grade:
>   Essay Word Count:
>   School / Organization Name: **Name** Teacher Name: **Name** Teacher Email: **Email** Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States? **Answer** School / Organization Address: **Address** School / Organization City: **City** School / Organization State: **State** School / Organization Zip Code: **Zip Code** School / Organization Phone: **Phone Number** School / Organization Email: **Email** How did you find out about this contest? **Answer** Essay Document: **internet link**

The bold parts are the parts I want

Right now the code I have works for everything, except it cannot seem to handle the paragraph part.

When it exports to Excel document, it adds in the header for the next section [Here is a picture of the spreadsheet. The bold text is being imported correctly, the non-bold text next to it should not be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au992.png)

I have very little experience with VBA, but some python and java knowledge. I know there is a **`RegEx`** option, but I have no idea how to use them in VBA.

Is there any way to salvage the paragraph code I have?

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim vPara As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim aa As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim sLink As String
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\labuser\Desktop\studentinfo.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook'


 If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
 MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
 End If
 On Error Resume Next
 Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 bXStarted = True
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
 'Open the workbook to input the data
 Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
 Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

 'Process each selected record
  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  sText = olItem.Body
  vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
  vPara = Split(sText, Chr(13))
  'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
  rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  rCount = rCount + 1

 'Check each line of text in the message body
  For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Name:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Do you current reside in the United States?") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address 2:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "City:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "State:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Zip Code:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Country:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Phone:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Citizenship:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Grade:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Essay Word Count:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
Next i
    For aa = UBound(vPara) To 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, vPara(aa), "School / Organization Name: ") > 0 Then
        vText = Split(vPara(aa), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(1), "School / Organization Name: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(2), "Teacher Name: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(3), "Teacher Email: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(4), " Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States?", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("R" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(5), " School / Organization Address: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("S" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(6), " School / Organization City: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("T" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(7), " School / Organization State: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("U" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(8), " School / Organization Zip Code: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("V" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Phone: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("W" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(10), " School / Organization Email: ", ""))
    End If
Next aa
xlWB.Save

Next olItem
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If you know it will always be "School / Organization Name: {some text} Teacher Name: {other text} etc" then you can use Instr() to find the position of the first label, then use Instr() again for the second label - you can then use those two positions with Mid() to extract the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments on / Compare it with your Code -

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim sText As String
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim sLink As String
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim sReplace As String

    FilePath = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx" 'the path of the xl workbook'


    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    '// Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath) ' Open xlFile
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1") ' use Sheet1 or Sheet name

    '// Process each selected Mail Item
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        sText = olItem.body ' Email Body
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13)) ' Chr(13) = Carriage return
'        vPara = Split(sText, Chr(13))

        '// Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        RowCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RowCount = RowCount + 1

        '// Check each line of text in the message body down loop
        For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

            '// InStr([start,]mainString, SearchedString[, compare])
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Name:") > 0 Then
                '// Split vItem : & :
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58)) ' Chr(58) = :
                '// Trim = String whose both side spaces needs to be trimmed
                xlSheet.Range("A" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1)) ' (1) = Position
            End If

            '// Do you current reside in the United States?
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Do you current reside in the United States?") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("B" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Address:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("C" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Address 2:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address 2:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("D" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// City:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "City:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("E" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// State:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "State:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("F" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Zip Code:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Zip Code:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("G" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Country:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Country:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("H" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Phone:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Phone:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("I" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Email:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("J" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Citizenship:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Citizenship:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("K" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Grade:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Grade:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("L" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Essay Word Count:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Essay Word Count:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("M" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// School / Organization Name
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization Name:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("N" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(1), "Teacher Name", ""))
            End If

            '// Teacher Name
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Teacher Name:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("O" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(2), "Teacher Email", ""))
            End If

            '// Teacher Email
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Teacher Email:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(32))
                xlSheet.Range("P" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(10))
            End If

            '// Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States?
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States?") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(32)) 'Chr(32) = space
                xlSheet.Range("Q" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(22))
            End If

            '// School / Organization Address:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization Address:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("R" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(4), "School / Organization City", ""))
            End If

            '// School / Organization City:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization City:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("S" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(5), "School / Organization State", ""))
            End If

            '// School / Organization State:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization State:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("T" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(6), "School / Organization Zip Code", ""))
            End If

            '// School / Organization Zip Code:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization Zip Code:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("U" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(7), "School / Organization Phone", ""))
            End If

            '// School / Organization Phone:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization Phone:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("V" & RowCount) = Trim(Replace(vItem(8), "School / Organization Email", ""))
            End If

            '// School / Organization Email:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "School / Organization Email") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(32))
                xlSheet.Range("W" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(56))
            End If

            '// How did you find out about this contest?
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "How did you find out about this contest?") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(32))
                xlSheet.Range("X" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(65))
            End If

            '// Essay Document:
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Essay Document:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("Y" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(10))
            End If

        Next i

        xlWB.Save

    Next olItem

    '// Save & close workbook
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    If bXStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    '// Cleanup
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: the two new if statements you provided worked perfectly! However when it gets to the third section (the teacher email section) it is not "stripping". As in it puts that answer, and the whole next line below it. Is this because the question is split between two line?

Comment: this looks great! It works really really well, except for some of the information is not copying over correctly. Specifically teacher email just inputs Name:, Is your school/organization based in the United States? just inputs based, School/Organization Email: inputs Phone:, and How did you find out about this contest? just inputs you into the excel document. Also, I realized I made a spelling mistake, it should be Do you currently reside in the United States. I tried to fix it and it gave me a run time error 9. You have already helped so much, so I hate to ask more.

Comment: I tried to change the trim portion of the code to make it similar to the other ones that did work and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: any chance you have an idea about the weird parsing it has been doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a known template that provides static start and stop points for the text parsing of the email body. I've put the actual mechanics of stripping out the desired values into a 'helper' sub.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const testString As String = "Name: Do you currently reside in the United States? " & _
    "Address: City: State: Zip Code: Phone: Email: Citizenship: Grade: Essay Word Count: " & _
    "School / Organization Name: SO Name Teacher Name: T Name Teacher Email: T Email " & _
    "Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States? Answer " & _
    "School / Organization Address: Address School / Organization City: City School / " & _
    "Organization State: State School / Organization Zip Code: Zip Code School / Organization " & _
    "Phone: Phone Number School / Organization Email: Email How did you find out about this " & _
    "contest? Answer Essay Document: internet link"

Sub main()
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    'Somewhere here you get the body of the email
    'I am using the sample string you provided in
    'your question made into a public string above.

    parseEmail testString, vVALs

    'for testing purposes
    'For v = LBound(vVALs) To UBound(vVALs)
    '    Debug.Print vVALs(v)
    'Next v

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp)
            .Resize(1, UBound(vVALs) + 1).Offset(1, 0) = vVALs
            Erase vVALs
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub parseEmail(ByVal str As String, ByRef pcs As Variant)
    Dim tmp As String, v As Long, vSRTs As Variant, vSTPs As Variant

    vSRTs = Array("School / Organization Name: ", "Teacher Name: ", "Teacher Email: ", _
                  "organization based in the United States? ", "School / Organization Address: ", _
                  "School / Organization City: ", "School / Organization State: ", _
                  "School / Organization Zip Code: ", "School / Organization Phone: ", _
                  "School / Organization Email: ", "find out about this contest? ", _
                  "Essay Document: ")
    vSTPs = Array(" Teacher", " Teacher", " Is your school", " School / Or", " School / Or", _
                  " School / Or", " School / Or", " School / Or", " School / Or", _
                  " How did you find", " Essay ")

    For v = LBound(vSRTs) To UBound(vSRTs) - 1
        str = Mid$(str, InStr(1, str, vSRTs(v), vbTextCompare) + Len(vSRTs(v)))
        tmp = tmp & Left$(str, InStr(1, str, vSTPs(v), vbTextCompare) - 1) & ChrW(8203)
    Next v
    str = Mid$(str, InStr(1, str, vSRTs(v), vbTextCompare) + Len(vSRTs(v)))
    tmp = tmp & str

    pcs = Split(tmp, ChrW(8203))

End Sub
```

Of course, this does depend upon maintaining the template format of the incoming email body but generally those are fairly regular. There is very little actual code here; most of the text and space is taken up by the test string and the storage / assignment of the start and stop header values.